# Does google index content that's inserted using setTimeout after the page is loaded?

Tags: seo, google, googlebot, javascript

Let's say we have this code

```
<body>
  content-1
</body>

<script>
  setTimeout(changeBodyContentTo("content-2"), 5000);
</script>
```

In this case will google crawl and index content-1 or content-2? And how we can test that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google renders pages and waits for a while before taking a snapshot of the page. Last I checked you had about 5 seconds to render what Google would see.

So I suspect this may not get indexed.

You can test this with the url inspection tool or one of Google's testing tools which will show you the rendered html that they may use. Note that timings in the live tests are different to the real Googlebot.